# Extract portion of nested tibbles?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I've got a pile of nested tibbles that are from the tidyrss package. The data looks like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is take the four common items from each tibble and tidy them, so that the output looks like this:

| item_title | item_link | item_description | item_pub_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| title from article 1 | some url | longer text | posix date |
| title from article 2 | some url | longer text | posix date |
| title from article 3 | some url | longer text | posix date |
| title from article 4 | some url | longer text | posix date |

Thus far I've tried unlist() and deframe() and both of those just make a general mess of things - and an added twist is not all the list items are tibbles. Some are functions, and I want to ignore those. What's the best tidyverse approach to tackle this task?

Comment: Can you give us the URL where you got the feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map_dfr` seems to do what you want! It loops over a list and applies a function to each one - in this case, the only "function" we want to apply is returning the data frame/tibble, but that also allows us to skip the functions:

```r
clean_feed_df <- list(
  data.frame(item_title=sample(letters, 3), 
             item_link=sample(letters, 3),
             item_desc=sample(letters, 3),
             item_date=sample(letters, 3)),
  data.frame(item_title=as.character(sample(1:100, 5)), 
             item_link=as.character(sample(1:100, 5)),
             item_desc=as.character(sample(1:100, 5)),
             item_date=as.character(sample(1:100, 5))),
  function(x)sum(x)
)

map_dfr(clean_feed_df, function(rssentry){
  if(is(rssentry, "data.frame")){
    return(rssentry)
  }
})
```

which returns

```
  item_title item_link item_desc item_date
1          s         s         u         i
2          x         d         o         x
3          t         x         d         h
4         40        51        21        91
5          4        25        37        34
6          5        44        18        71
7         65        70        83        90
8         32        85        76        89
```